# Why instanceof returns false for a child object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, inheritance, instanceof

I have the Child class that extends Parent class.
So let say I created a new instance "child" out of the Child class.
When I check the condition `child instanceof Child`, it returns false.
However, `child instanceof Parent` returns true.

Why does this so?

**EDIT**

So I found this only happens when I extend the Child class with Error class.
Let me leave the code example below.

```js
class Child extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
const ch = new Child();
console.log(ch instanceof Child);
```

**2nd EDIT**

```
class PullCreditError extends Error {
  public name: string;
  public message: string;
  public attemptsRemaining: number;
  constructor(message: string, attemptsRemaining: number) {
    super();
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, PullCreditError);
    this.name = 'PullCreditError';
    this.message = message;
    this.attemptsRemaining = attemptsRemaining;
  }
}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added my code example. I actually had Child class inherited from javascript Error class.

Comment: this doesn't look like javascript. are you sure you're not using java?

Comment: @PhilippSander Have you never seen a JavaScript class before?

Comment: I never saw "constructor". it was just a question. I may be wrong.

Comment: @PhilippSander Welcome to ES2015 :P

Comment: @CertainPerformance haha looks like it! I'm really outdated when it comes to javascript. some backend-people don't care :D

Comment: Added my testing case failing...

Comment: Your snippet is returning true.  It's hard to see the relationship between your snippet and the picture of the error. How are they related?

Comment: @CertainPerformance added my actual code. this is typescript tho..

Comment: Compiling your typescript and running *still* shows `PullCreditError` to be an `instanceof` `Error` for me.

Comment: this drives me crazy. If I extend PullCreditError to any other class that I create by myself, it works. but it I extend it from Error, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a documented bug:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15875

> Extending built-ins like Error, Array, and Map may no longer work
>
> As part of substituting the value of this with the value returned by a super(...) call, subclassing Error, Array, and others may no longer work as expected. This is due to the fact that constructor functions for Error, Array, and the like use ECMAScript 6's new.target to adjust the prototype chain; however, there is no way to ensure a value for new.target when invoking a constructor in ECMAScript 5. Other downlevel compilers generally have the same limitation by default.

The recommendation is to adjust the prototype manually using `setPrototypeOf` in the constructor. A fix for your `PullCreditError` class would look like this:

```
export class PullCreditError extends Error {
  public name: string;
  public message: string;
  public attemptsRemaining: number;
  constructor(message: string, attemptsRemaining: number) {
    super();
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, PullCreditError.prototype); // <-------
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, PullCreditError);
    this.name = 'PullCreditError';
    this.message = message;
    this.attemptsRemaining = attemptsRemaining;
  }
}
```