# Why inheriting from Array not working in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I tried to inherit from `Array`, but the `instanceof` not working.

```
class MyList<T> extends Array<T> {}

const l = new MyList<string>()
console.log(l instanceof MyList)  // false <- WRONG
console.log(l instanceof Array)   // true
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why instanceof returns false for a child object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229574/why-instanceof-returns-false-for-a-child-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jcalz the code should be as below, [more details](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work)

```
class MyList<T> extends Array<T> {
    constructor() {
        super()
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, MyList.prototype)
    }

}
const l = new MyList<string>()
console.log(l instanceof MyList)  // false <- WRONG
console.log(l instanceof Array)   // true
```